# JavaScript is linked, but won't show up in the Chrome Developer Console

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, chrome-dev-editor

I've been working my way through the Udemy Web Development Bootcamp, and I am on a unit that asks us to make a To Do list so we can practice creating arrays, adding to and removing from them, and so on...

I understand the code that the instructor has written, and I've checked my code compared to his and I can't find a difference.

But, in his version, when he opens the Chrome Developer Console, and types the input into the prompts, the console reacts accordingly (i.e. returning values, or evaluating expressions), but when I do it, nothing shows up.

The prompt box is responsive, and understands my conditionals because it changes depending on what I type in, but nothing is showing up in the console.

Can you help me? This is my first Stack Overflow post so be nice!

Thanks,
Jake

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title> To Do List</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

    <h1>To Do List</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>"New" - Add Item</li>
        <li>"List" - View List</li>
        <li>"Quit" - Quit App</li>
    </ul>




</body>

</html>

    var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

while(input !== "quit"){
    if(input === "list") {
        console.log(todos);
    } else if(input === "new") {
        var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
        todos.push(newTodo);
    }  

    //run code again
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("Okay, you Quit the App");
```

Comment: You need to add your script to script tags like: `<script>var todos...</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have included one js file by putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`, but the code at the bottom of the html file won't work, because it needs to be surrounded by script tag. Just like this:

```
<script>
    var todos = ["Buy New Turtle"];

var input = prompt("What would you like to do?");

while(input !== "quit"){
    if(input === "list") {
        console.log(todos);
    } else if(input === "new") {
        var newTodo = prompt("Enter new todo");
        todos.push(newTodo);
    }  

    //run code again
    input = prompt("What would you like to do?");
}
console.log("Okay, you Quit the App");
</script>
```

Also note that the script tag should be inside of html tag.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify this, but the JS file is actually a separate file in my folder...I just pasted them both here so you had everything. Do I still need to surround it with script tags?

Comment: It's kinda late answer, but yes. Make sure that script tag is at the bottom of the body tag so it won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Jake: I have tested your code by running in a browser. The issue you are facing will be solved by following @Sahee advise. Move your code before  and enclosed within .... tags.

You need to follow two rules.

1. All script commands should always be between ....
2. Everything in a web page either html, css or javascript should be between .... tags. These tags denote start and end of document. Anything outside of html may result in unexpected behavior.